# Vertical skip between p{...} rows of tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, paragraphs

I want to increase a bit the vertical spacing in my `tabular` table.  I did something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur & adipisicing elit \\[6pt]
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

but to my surprise, it doesn't work - it seems that the extra vertical space from `[12pt]` is somehow eaten by the space beneath the (shorter) parbox.  What should I do?

Comment: You could redefine the `\arraystretch` length, stretching the space between rows.

Comment: And what if I want to increase the spacing of only one row?  (And yes, this *is* sometimes justified IMHO.)

Comment: The implementation of `\\[..]` in LaTeX tables is one of its more interesting "features".  The expected behaviour is that the user finds the behaviour unexpected. Impossible to change without breaking every existing document that has a table though....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put a strut in the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{6pt} & adipisicing elit \\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, though a bit hackish.  (I thought about it too, though I didn't remember the syntax of `\rule`, so thanks!)  If nothing more "elegant" shows up, I'll accept this one...

Comment: @mbork don't wait:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: having seen the other answers, I can see that you're probably right...

Answer (score 1):

The `\\` mechanism can be used, but one has to account for the height of the `\parbox`, either manually or automatically.  The other option, if all rows are to be adjusted, is to use the `\extrarowheight` parameter of the `array` package, or else `\arraystretch` as was mentioned in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

ORIGINAL

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur & adipisicing elit \\[6pt]
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
\end{tabular}

\hrulefill

CAN DO A SINGLE ROW, MANUALLY ACCOUNT FOR \verb|\parbox| HEIGHT

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur & adipisicing elit \\[18pt]%
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
\end{tabular}

\hrulefill

CAN DO A SINGLE ROW,AUTO- ACCOUNT FOR \verb|\parbox| HEIGHT

\def\x{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur}
\setbox0=\hbox{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\x}}

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
  \x & adipisicing elit \\[\dimexpr\dp0+6pt\relax]%
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
\end{tabular}

\hrulefill

AFFECTS EVERY ROW:

\setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur & adipisicing elit \\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have vertical lines, then this can be solved by

```
\noalign{\vspace{6pt}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur & adipisicing elit\\
  \noalign{\vspace{6pt}}%
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore & et dolore magna aliqua.\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With `\noalign` vertical mode material can be added that is not subjected to the current table alignment.

The main disadvantage of this approach is that vertical lines get interrupted:

> [image: Result interrupted vertical lines]

Therefore LaTeX uses this implementation for *negative* lengths. Then the problem with the vertical lines is much smaller, because they just overlap in most cases.

If the value is positive, then LaTeX adds an invisible rule. Height and width are zero, the depth is the sum of the given value and the depths of the *standard* tabular line, the depth of a strutbox increased by `\arraystretch`.

A better implementation would have keep track of the maximum depth of all cells in the row. The increased memory usage and slower run time might have been an noticeable issue in the early days of LaTeX. Nowadays implementing such a feature is no fun at all, because 99% of the implementation would have to deal with package compatibility (`array`, `colortbl` and many, many other table packages).